# VLC - Get played file path

Tags: linux, lua, vlc, httpserver

I would like to get the path of the file currently played by vlc. It seems that [information can be obtained using the http server of vlc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436861/get-now-playing-info-from-vlc-command-line).

Since I don't know much about http, I was not able to do it even with the help of the previous link or the [vlc documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Advanced_Use_of_VLC/).

To start an http server, I am supposed to use the command `vlc -I http`.

**First question**: Since this command does not open a vlc window, should I open a vlc window by myself after using this command? Or before? Or maybe it does not matter?

So I chose to first use the command, then open a vlc window and play an mp3 file in it.

To get information from vlc, the first link says:

> You can then retrieve player status and track information by issuing a GET request to http://127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.xml

I am not sure how to do a GET request. I tried wget:

```
~$ wget http://127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.xml
--2020-12-22 12:17:22--  http://127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.xml
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Client error

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
```

I tried to add my username and password but it did not work:

```
~$ wget --user my_username --password my_password http://127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.xml
--2020-12-22 12:18:31--  http://127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.xml
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Client error
Authentication selected: Basic realm="VLC stream"
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Client error

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
```

I tried to follow the advice in the vlc documentation:

> Use a browser to go to http://your_host_machine:port

I went to `http://localhost:8080` (which seemed the most likely host machine and port) but similarly to wget I am asked a username and a password and I don't know which ones I am supposed to set.

I found [here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&p=500500) that the username should be left empty and that the password could be set in vlc parameters > Interface > Main interfaces > Lua. So I set a password and a source directory in the section "Lua HTTP". Now when I use `http://localhost:8080` I can enter my password and I see the list of the files in the source directory that I specified.

With all that, the wget command still returns the same output.

**Second question:** Could you tell my how to make it work?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1

VLC version: 3.0.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set an admin password when you start VLC with the flag:

```
--http-password
```

You should then be able to run wget or curl with the admin username and the password specified to get the information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I started both the http server and vlc with this argument. When I use the command `vlc --http-password my_password` I get the error `Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket` is it a problem? Unfortunately, when I then use `wget --user= --password=my_password http://localhost:8080/requests/status.xml` I still get the same error.

Comment: OK. Start vlc to the background first with "vlc -I http &" Then use "vlc --http-password".

Comment: It worked once I emptied the vlc Lua parameter "source directory". Unfortunately, the file status.xml does not contain the playing file information :(. Strangely, it seems to believe that vlc is stopped (`<state>stopped</state>`) even if I am currently playing a file.

Comment: You will have to play the track through the http interface